# Шпион и разведчик

Tags: синонимы

Помните популярный некогда юмористический рассказ "Штирлиц, или Как размножаются ежики"? В частности, там был такой абзац: "*Войдя в ватерклозет, Штирлиц обнаружил свежую надпись: "Штирлиц - скотина и русский шпион". Штирлиц старательно зачеркнул слово "шпион" и  надписал слово "разведчик", а внизу приписал: "Борман - тоже скотина".*
Тут сразу видна разница между словами "шпион" и "разведчик". Оба слова означают одно и то же, но, если "разведчик" звучит благородно, то "шпион" носит явно выраженную негативную окраску.
Почему так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если брать изначальное понимание слов, то "разведчик" - это тот, кто ходит в разведку, т. е. с риском для жизни изучает расположение неприятеля, а если получится, с собой еще и языка приводит. Под шпионом же с самого начала подразумевался некий "штирлиц", обманывающий всех в глубоком тылу. Уже из этого описание видно, что с морально-этической точки зрения действия разведчика выглядят благороднее методов шпиона, поэтому неудивительно, что за первым словом закрепился положительный облик, а за вторым - отрицательный.

В дальнейшем, когда наших шпионов стали изображать как положительных героев, произошло еще большее разделение слов именно по оценке действий. Наш шпион хороший, поэтому он "разведчик", их шпион плохой, поэтому и остается "шпионом".

Answer (score 3):

Слово "шпион" - заимствованное. Обычно используется в сочетании с "вражеский". Отсюда и "негатив".